# Can I boot Ubuntu from a (sometimes) write-protected USB drive?

Tags: ubuntu

I often boot from an Ubuntu DVD to have a clean system for doing various tasks (eg. accessing my NAS with the root account, rescuing data from old HDDs etc). I like that booting from the DVD gives me an always (well, as close as possible for me) clean system without the possibility of corrupting it.

But I don't like that booting from the DVD takes over an hour! Since the DVD drive is making noise like jumping back and forth a lot during that time, I think that I could speed up that process a lot by booting from a USB pen drive, which does not have a head that has to move to get another portion of data. But USB pen drives are usually not write protected, so I do not have the "write protection guarantees a clean system" feature of the DVD any more.

1. Could I write an Ubuntu ISO to a USB pen drive that has a physical write protection switch, then set the switch to "ON" and have the same benefits as booting from DVD, plus possibly higher speed?
2. Could I even switch off the write protection, boot from the drive and update the system on the drive (or eg. save my Wifi key, *Kezboard lazout* etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Linux "live" images are inherently read-only because they use a SquashFS archive for their "root" filesystem. Unlike normal filesystems, SquashFS doesn't support in-place modifications and is always mounted read-only – it's more like a zip archive than a filesystem.

If you write such an image to a USB stick, it won't become a standard installation – it'll still be booting from a read-only SquashFS root. You might have an option for "persistence" to save your settings and such, but this is implemented as a second image – a writable "overlay" on top of the read-only SquashFS-based rootfs. Note that in most cases the overlay is set up to store changes to the base OS as well – not only to your settings. But deleting the file containing the persistent overlay image would return the USB stick to its original state.

(That being said, an OS doesn't really "get corrupted" out of nowhere...)

Additionally, if the ISO image in fact contains an ISO-9660 filesystem, it doesn't matter what media you write it on – the OS is going to treat it as read-only because ISO-9660 isn't really structured to support in-place modifications either. To "update" either an ISO-9660 image or a SquashFS image, you'd have to extract and rebuild it. On the other hand, UDF that's used on DVDs *could* be updated in-place, but I think most Linux OS images use ISO-9660.

Comment: "(That being said, an OS doesn't really "get corrupted" out of nowhere...)" – Yes, but it could always be me doing stupid things or having malware on old HDDs. ;-)

Comment: Generally malware doesn't get run just by looking at it (assuming it's Linux malware in the first place), so if you deliberately `sudo ./shady_exe`, I'd probably put that under "doing stupid things" as well...

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'd put that under "doing stupid things" or under "theoretically possible malware", eg. using a vulnerability in a widely used linux jpeg library that is unnoticed for a long time.